# while loop data doesnt print on screen - PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone see an error in this? I dont get the results printed which is expected from the second loop. How ever the second loop headers are printed without an issue.

I'm trying to print data from a SQL database.

```
  <?php

$con= new mysqli('localhost','root','','regional_data');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {exit('Connection failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk='$distUsr'");

echo "<table cellpadding='2' class='tablet' cellspacing='0'>";
echo
"<tr>
<th></th>"
."<th>"."Starting Cheque No"."</th>"
."<th>"."Ending Cheque No"."</th>"
."<th>"."Total No of Cheques remaining"."</th>"
."<th>"."Cheque Type"."</th>"
."</tr>";

while ($reca = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' ></td>";
echo "<td>".trim($reca["sbstart"])."</td>";
echo "<td>".trim($reca["sbend"])."</td>";
echo "<td>".trim($reca["totsb"])."</td>";
echo "<td>SB</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

        echo "<table cellpadding='2' class='tablet' cellspacing='0'>";
        echo
        "<tr>
        <th></th>"
        ."<th>"."Starting Cheque No"."</th>"
        ."<th>"."Ending Cheque No"."</th>"
        ."<th>"."Total No of Cheques remaining"."</th>"
        ."<th>"."Cheque Type"."</th>"
        ."</tr>";
        while ($reca = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' ></td>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["gwstart"])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["gwend"])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["totgw"])."</td>";
        echo "<td>GW</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";


$con->close(); 
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($reca = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

This fetches *all results* from the result set. After that the result set is exhausted, which is why the loop ever ends. There are no more results to be fetched from the same result set afterwards.

Either issue a new query, or save the data into an array which you can loop over again as many times as you want.

Comment: actually when used in the context of a `while` loop it loops through the items and uses the current item in the array

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the same $result variable twice.

What I would do is the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk='$distUsr'");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk='$distUsr'");
```

Then your first while loop can use `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and the second one can use `mysqli_fetch_array($result2)`.

Hope this helps!